# Building Unicenta oPos from source on Windows

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, opos

I'm having lots of difficulties building Unicenta's Point of sale software from source.

- I'm on Windows and using NetBeans v8.1 (I've tried both SE and EE, don't know if that matters)
- Maven has been downloaded and added to the path variable.
- Jdk 1.8 installed and JAVA_HOME variable created
- Downloaded the Unicenta oPos v3.91.3 source code (from Source Forge) and opened project in NetBeans
- Right-clicked project in projects pane, selected 'Build with Dependencies'

**RESULT**

```
cd C:\Users\Jakov\Documents\Java projekti\Unicenta oPos 3.91.3; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 install\""
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.unicenta:unicentaopos:jar:3.91.3
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 346, column 21

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

It then proceeds to download various packages:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1/commons-logging-1.1.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1/commons-logging-1.1.pom (7 KB at 43.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://s448089793.websitehome.co.uk/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/2.0.6/spring-core-2.0.6.pom
```

This message shows up on several packages:

```
Downloading: http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/2.0.6/spring-core-2.0.6.pom
velj 25, 2016 10:17:57 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected [rememberMe="deleteMe", version:0, domain:bits.netbeans.org, path:/nexus, expiry:Thu Feb 25 10:17:57 CET 2016] Illegal path attribute "/nexus". Path of origin: "/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/2.0.6/spring-core-2.0.6.pom"
```

And finally:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3:10.127s
Finished at: Thu Feb 25 10:20:59 CET 2016
Final Memory: 10M/66M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project unicentaopos: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.unicenta:unicentaopos:jar:3.91.3: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.unicenta:pos:jar:1.0, com.handpoint:headstartsimulator:jar:1.1.2, com.handpoint:heft:jar:1.1.0, com.handpoint:hal-pc:jar:1.1.2: Could not find artifact com.unicenta:pos:jar:1.0 in private-repo (http://s448089793.websitehome.co.uk/maven2/) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The first warning is solved after adding a `<version>` tag for maven-jar-plugin. But I can't figure out the solution to the errors. I've tried adding Apache's Maven repository to the POM, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, not sure why Unicenta doesn't pack the right pom inside the .zip file they provide.

Just download the pom.xml file from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/files/source/

[image: Unicenta POM]

And use it to replace the pom.xml file inside the netbeans project (...\unicentaopos-3.91.3-source\pom.xml)

Build again and there you go